# Simple, non-scrollable table in android (views)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-tablelayout, android-gridlayout

I see TableLayout, GridLayout, GridView... I have fairly understood what more or less each of them is but I still need some help.

I have the following FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And I want to create a 4x3 table (4 rows, 3 columns) with 12 of the above FrameLayouts and some aspects in mind:

It's not going to be scrollable, it's going to have a relative to the screen height, each cell will have the same relative dimensions and its items to be easily "manipulated".

By manipulated I mean see check the clicks happening on each cell and do something.

In this case that I described, what is the most suitable view to contain those FrameLayouts?

Comment: Probably TableLayout? GridView is overkill for what you are doing (and not really what you want), GridLayout is nice but is API 14+ and can give some overlap issues.

Comment: @zgc7009 14+ is fine. Wouldn't the GridView with an Adapter be handier to populate?

Comment: If you feel comfortable with it, go at it with a GridView. It will certainly handle what you are trying to do, but it seems a bit bulky for your needs. I would really work with a TableLayout if you don't plan on scrolling. GridView has a lot of coding efficiencies built particularly for scrolling.

Comment: @zgc7009 I see. Could you describe an ideal plan to handle those 12 children? E.g. 4x3 loops to create it programmatically (because 12 is a lot for copy/pasting)? That's my only burden. I will accept is as an answer.